# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() Race Condition / Deadlock

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, deadlock, race-condition

I was wondering if Android's BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() message can result in race conditions and/or deadlocks? I have read Android's developer pages in regards to the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method but cannot discern the answer to my question. Let's assume that I have implemented code that writes a number to a .txt file each time I receive a new text message. If I receive two text messages at exactly the same time do I need to worry about the file being updated at the same time?

Thanks in advance for your help, suggestions, and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to worry.

The `onReceive` method is called from the main thread of your application. Therefore, only one can be executed at a time. (This also mean that you must never block that thread, and try to return as quickly as possible)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am doing very little work on the main thread so I hopefully will never reach the 10 second timeout. I will accept your answer once SO allows me to do so.